# How to redirect superuser to specific page in Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-views, django-templates

I want to send the superuser to the dashboard (home) after login. But a normal user will redirect to the store page so how can I do it?

This is the logic I am using in the views.py file so what changes do I need to do?

**views.py**

```
@unauthenticated_user
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        user = authenticate(request, username = username, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('store')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username OR Password is incorrect')

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'store/login.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    
    path('register/', views.registerPage, name="register"),
    path('login/', views.loginPage, name="login"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    
    path('dashboard/', views.home, name='dashboard'),
    path('products/', views.products, name='products'),
    path('customer/<str:pk>/', views.customer, name='customer'),
    path('profile/', views.profilePage, name="profile"),

    path('cart/', views.cart, name='cart'),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('', views.store, name='store'),
    path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name='update_item'),
    path('process_order/', views.processOrder, name='process_order'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code ->

```
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    if user.is_superuser:
        return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        return redirect('store')
else:
    messages.info(request, 'Username OR Password is incorrect')
```

you are checking if user is superuser -> `user.is_superuser`  and it returns True it is and False if its not. maybe it helps you.

For a good practice to do check this code i think this is better to do ->

```
if user is None:
   message.info(request, 'Username OR password is incorrect')

login(request, user)
if user.is_superuser:
    
    return (redirect('dashboard')
return redirect('store')
```